# get ordered integer vector from another vector

Tags: matlab

I have a vector:

```
v1 = [13 13 13 13 5 5 5 2 2 5 5];
```

and would like to create another vector, `v2`, such that if an element in `v1` is the same as the previous element, it gets the same ordered (sequential) integer, eg:

```
v2 = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4];
```

Comment: `cumsum([true diff(v1)~=0])`? (There must be a duplicate for this, but I can't find it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formalising [Luis comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69343946/get-ordered-integer-vector-from-another-vector#comment122563836_69343946) as a (community wiki) answer, you could do

```
cumsum([1, diff(v1)~=0]);
```

Which uses `cumsum` to do the running sum of a true/false array identifying where one element is different to the previous one, i.e. 1 where the value changed, 0 otherwise.